# line continuation when using docker exec bash with double quotes

Tags: docker

I want to be able to pass variables inside the `docker exec bash -c " " which also include line continuation character. Consider below command which works with line continuation but without variables inside the bash command

```
docker exec -t $hostname bash -c 'authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth \
--ldapserver="myldap.docker.com" --ldapbasedn="dc=docker,dc=com" --enablesssd \
--enablesssdauth --enableldaptls --enablemkhomedir --disablecache --disablecachecreds \
--update'
```

If i want to pass variables inside the bash e.g. `--ldapserver='$ldaphost' --ldapbasedn='dc=$domain,dc=com'` and i need to replace single quotes `'` by double quotes `"` and also remove the line continuation `'\'`,otherwise it doesn't work.

```
docker exec -t $hostname bash -c "authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver='$ldaphost' --ldapbasedn='dc=$domain,dc=com' --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enableldaptls --enablemkhomedir --disablecache --disablecachecreds --update"
```

Removing the line continuation takes away the aesthetics of the script. Are there any alternatives for this.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to double the backslash, in order to escape it from expansion by the invoking shell?

Comment: actually i had already tried it..running the command did not give any error, but it also did nothing. the files these commands are supposed to modify were untouched

Comment: Actually it seems to work, i was testing with same variable values and hoping for file to update..but the command does not update the timestamp if there is nothing to update. so i checked again with different values and it actually updates the files. Thanks for suggesting it again.